# How to store xml type data from sql server to the arraylist in java

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, spring-boot, arraylist

I am retrieving data from the MySQL server, where one column name is having the datatype as XML. I need the data inside XML attribute for some comparison. I want to store data type and values of the XML attribute in one `List<ArrayList<String>>` because another side of my data to be compared in ArrayList. Suggest me using the ResultSet to access from the database, How I can store in java `List<ArrayList<String>>`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to fetch the data from DB?

Comment: Yes I am able to fetch the data from the database.

Comment: Can you please add it into the question, so that I can have a look

Comment: I need only the values of the XML not with attribute type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resultset has `getSQLXML()` method which can be used for fetching XML from the xml datatype column.

Use `ResultSetMetaData` to confirm the datatype returned by xml datatype column.

Use getString() method from SQLXML interface to get XML data in the form of string and then use JAXB for converting XML to POJO.

Alternatively, you can get the binary stream from SQLXML and use parsers such as SAX, DOM or StAX parser.

Comment: Sorry for mistake..
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not have any data type like xml. The most common way to store xml is in the form of clob.

`ResultSet` interface has `getClob()` method through which you can fetch xml from the database and extract it to string using `getSubString` method.

Use Jaxb for converting xml to java objects and apply your comparison logic. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about sql-server

Comment: yes it is sql server. Sorry it is by mistake mysql. I want to store that data from sql server.